# Javascript if condition always evaluating false

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a javascript function for which the purpose is to get the number of files browsed.

The function gets a value `len` and based on that value, checks some conditions. In addition to that, I'm trying to retrieve the IDs of four file upload controls.

```
 function alertMe(len)
 {
     var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
     var fu2 = document.getElementById("FileUpload2");
     var fu3 = document.getElementById("FileUpload3");
     var fu4 = document.getElementById("FileUpload4");
     var myCars=new Array(fu1,fu2,fu3,fu4)
     var l=0;
     for(var i=0;i<myCars.length;i++)
     {
         if(myCars[i].value!=null)
             l++;
     }
     if(len>6)
     {
         if(len==7 && l<=3)
           window.location="uploo.aspx";
         else if(len==8 && l<=2)
           window.location="uploo.aspx";
         else if(len==9 && l<=1)
           window.location="uploo.aspx";
         else
           alert("you cant keep more than 10 files in your table,,delete some files first and then upload");
         return false;
     }
     else
         window.location="uploo.aspx";
 }
```

The function does not give any errors but is not working properly.
Suppose `len == 7` and `l == 3`, then it should call `uploo.aspx`, but rather it shows me the alert messages.

Why is the `if(len==7 && l<=3)` not evaluating to `true` in this case?

Comment: Is type of len a number or a string?

Comment: could you post the call to alertMe -- I want to see what's being passed for len.

Comment: its a number but i have passed it like len.ToString();

Comment: Have you verified that l and len contain the values you expect? It seems to me that you should be checking for an empty string, if(myCars[i].value!=null || myCars[i].value!="").

Comment: @Phaedrus,,hmm but that does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing a bunch of extra work for tools that are already out there.
Try out [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). I believe you can set a limit for the number of files that can be uploaded, as well as limit the types of files that can be uploaded. They can also upload multiple files at once.

Comment: actually the no of files user uploads are stored in a gridview,,and i m trying to limit my number of rows in grdiview and not on uploaded files

Answer (score 0):

For sanity's sake, I'd start by adding the missing semicolon to the end of your `var myCars` line.  In some IE browsers, they'll choke in weird ways if you're missing those semicolons.

If all four of the vars fu1-4 have values, then your variable `l` is going to be 4, which you don't explicitly check for, and which will fall through to the `alert()` error case (assuming `len > 6`).

I'd liberally add some more debugging tracer output -- add an `alert('l=' + l ', and len=' + len)` after your for loop, for example.

Answer (score 0):

try using `if(myCars[i].value)` instead of checking against `null` - value is a string and even an empty string is unequal null.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the values using firebug:

```
console.log(l);
```

If you put this within the switch you should be albe to see the values that are being used in the firebug console.